# How SQL String Comparison Works?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I had a condition written like

```
IF(LEN(@strData) > 3 OR @strData > '255') BEGIN     
// Some Condition
END
```

This is written in a sp which i come across written by someone.
First Condition is clear if LEN > 3 its coming true for that condition.

But `> '255'` what does it mean ?

I passed random values like

```
@strData = 'add' Result true
@strData = 'a' Result true
@strData = '12hhd' Result false
```

I didn't understand what way it behaves.
That query is not commented why fellow developer writes that line.

In SQL String Comparison how it will work..
Please some make me clear.

**UPDATE :**

I need that same condition in C# for some purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server a  string comparison is done in alphabetical order. That is "allan" is greater than "alan" because alphabetically "alan" comes before "allan". So, numbers are treated the same when doing string comparison, they are treated in alphabetical order...so, '2' is greater than '12'...surprising, huh? Well, alphabetical string comparisons are done from left to right hence '2' is greater than '12'.
Now, in C#, there's absolutely no difference it behaves exactly the same as sql. To reinforce any possible doubts you might have...you can easily test it....

SQL

```
if '2' > '12'
    select '2 > 12';
else
    select '2 < 12';
```

C# Console App

```
        if ("2".CompareTo("12") < 0 )
            Console.WriteLine("2 is less than 12");
        else if ("2".CompareTo("12") > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("2 is greater than 12");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("2 is equal to 12");
```

Hope it makes sense for you

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple comaprision between two strings.

An SQL string comparision works like so:

```
Compare 'a' with '255' for '>'

 if length(a) < length(b) 
      pad a with spaces to be same length as b;
 for x = 0 to length(a) 
      if a(x) < b(x) return false;
      if a(x) > b(x) return true;
 return false;
```

In the case of your " 'a' > '255' "
     the ASCII/utf-8 letter 'a' is greater than the character '2' so it returns true on the first character comparision,